# Move CartoDB-Map to show full InfoWindow

Tags: carto, carto-js, infowindow

In CartoDB, if I customize the styles of an InfoWindow, the map moves not enough to always display the full InfoWindow.

For example: If I position the `div.cartodb-popup` to `left:26px` and `bottom:16px` to get it (the bottom left corner) open exactly where the user clicked, larger InfoWindows will not be displayed fully inside the map (Screenshot left), require the user to drag the map to fully see the infowindow (Screenshot right).

[image: Left: right now, wrong; Right: desired view]

How can I tell CartoDB to move the map X pixels more to the left or right and top or bottom, so the user can see the full InfoWindow (Screenshot right)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is easier as I thought (and did not work so far cause of a cache-problem) … but it worked by just adding a margin-top and margin-right to `div.cartodb-popup`

Comment: Great!! :) Could you mark your question as answered?